# calling Iterables.contains for a subfield of object list

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, guava

I would like to be able to test if a List contain an object with a given key-value

For example, I would like to do something like *Iterables.contains(l2, "lname", "Jordan"));*  instead of having to create all other Map objects like below in l2

```
//List<String> l = Arrays.asList("Mickael", "Jordan", "His Airness");
//System.out.println(Iterables.contains(l, "Jordan"));

Map<String, String> p1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
p1.put("fname", "Mickael");
p1.put("lname", "Jordan");
p1.put("nname", "His Airness");

Map<String, String> p2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
p2.put("fname", "Paul");
p2.put("lname", "Pierce");
p2.put("nname", "The Truth");
List<Map<String, String>> l2 = Arrays.asList(p1, p2);
Map<String, String> p3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
p3.put("fname", "Mickael"); //
p3.put("lname", "Jordan");
p3.put("nname", "His Airness"); //
System.out.println(Iterables.contains(l2, p3));
```

I'd like to know if there's such guava's function, and not doing a loop on l2 and testing each elt.get("lname")

***Edit***

3 solutions answered: trying to see which one is more perfomant

```
System.out.println(Iterables.any(l2, withEntry("lname", "Jordan"))); //@axtavt
System.out.println(has("lname", "Jordan")); //@JB
System.out.println(Iterables.any(l2, new KeyValuePredicate("lname", "Jordan"))); //@JB

public static Boolean has(final String key, final String value) {
    return Iterables.any(l2, new Predicate<Map<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Map<String, String> input) {
            return input.get(key).equals(value);
        }
    });
}

public static Predicate<Map<String, String>> withEntry(final String key, final String value) {
    return new Predicate<Map<String, String>>() {
        public boolean apply(Map<String, String> input) {
            return value.equals(input.get(key));
        }
    };
}

class KeyValuePredicate implements Predicate<Map<String, String>>{
private String key;
private String value;
public KeyValuePredicate(String key, String value) {
    super();
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}
@Override
public boolean apply(Map<String, String> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0.get(key).equals(value);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Iterables.any(l2, new Predicate<Map<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Map<String, String> input) {
        return input.get("lname").equals("Jordan");
    }
});
```

But you're using maps when you should use objects with properties.

Of course, if you need to do that multiple times, with various properties, you should transform the predicate into a non-anonymous, reusable class:

```
return Iterables.any(l2, new KeyValuePredicate("lname", "Jordan"));
```

Comment: KeyValuePredicate seems not existing in my guava version (r08)

Comment: Guava contributor here: @JBNizet is suggesting that you make your own `KeyValuePredicate` class, not referring to something already in Guava.  This is definitely the recommended solution, if (for some inexplicable reason) you don't want to iterate over the list (though you should, and you should also make the maps into proper objects instead of leaving them as maps).

Comment: in terms of perfomance the simple loop is necessarily faster?

Comment: Iterables.any is no magic. It loops over the list to find a matching element. Both should be equivalent, or at least the difference should be negligible.

Comment: Should you want to perform many lookups, you can reduce the O(L * N) complexity (L = lookups, N = number of elements in list) to O(L) by transforming your list to a Multimap. Do sth like this: Multimap<String, String> index = Multimaps.index(l2, MapFunctions.get("fname"); assertTrue(!index.get("Jordan").isEmpty());  You'll have to make the MapFunctions.get("fname") yourself. But JB Nizet is right: most likely you want to create classes instead of Map lookups.

Comment: @Dib Can you detail how it be possible to create classes for this example case?, Actually I chose the Map solution, because I'm fetching this data from a nosql db, what solution is better classes Vs multimaps? and thx

Comment: To answer that question I would have to go severely beyond the scope of this question. Any good introductory book on OOP can teach you the merits of choosing classes over maps (multi or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an appropriate [`Predicate`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) and use `Iterables.any()`:

```
public Predicate<Map<String, String>> withEntry(final String key, final String value) {
    return new Predicate<Map<String, String>>() {
        public boolean apply(Map<String, String> input) {
            return value.equals(input.get(key));
        }
    };
}

System.out.println(Iterables.any(l2, withEntry("lname", "Jordan")));
```

Comment: that works fine, trying to see if another solution is more perf

Answer (score 0):

Well this is straightforward.

You should create a proper entity class:

```
public class Person {

    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String nName;

    public Person(String fName, String lName, String nName) {
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.nName = nName;
    }

    public String getFName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public String getLName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public String getNName() {
        return nName;
    }

}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Person p1 = new Person("Mickael", "Jordan", "His Airness");

        for (Person person : list) {
            if (person.getFName().equals("Mickael")) {
                System.out.println("Mickael is in the list!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```